# javascript canvas drawImage using jpg image object has memory high usage in windows firefox

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, canvas, memory-leaks

before I question about problem, Sorry about my english skill.

I have written a remote desktop that displays desktop windows using jpg.
I send jpg binary 30 fps, and draw canvas.
after a few second ago, in firefox, memory usage very high. but chrome is not.
below is firefox about:memory Explicit Allocations and code.
[firefox about:memory Explicit Allocations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFTS2.png)

```
<canvas id="drawCanvas" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("drawCanvas").getContext("2d");
var image = new Image;
image.onload = function() {
    canvas.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
}

function start() {
    colSock = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:38935"); //websocket create
    colSock.binaryType = "arraybuffer"; 

    //connection open
    colSock.onopen = function(){
    };

    //receive message from server
    colSock.onmessage = function(evt){
        var dataview = new DataView(evt.data);
        draw(dataview, evt);
    };

    // connection close
    colSock.onclose = function() {
    };
    //connection error
    colSock.onerror = function (event) {
    };
};

function draw(dataview, evt) {
    var sequence = dataview.getUint32(1, true);
    var timestamp = dataview.getUint32(5, true);
    var jpegArrayBuffer = evt.data.slice(9, evt.data.byteLength, true);
    var jpgBlob = new Blob([jpegArrayBuffer], { type:"image/jpeg" });

    image.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(jpgBlob);
}
</script>
```

and also, sometimes, it has no high memory usage in explicit allocation. but canvas-2d-pixels and imagelib-surface-cache-estimated-total has high memory usage.
[Other Measurements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p99X6.png)

In my opinion, firefox does not release image immediately, and chrome release immediately. but I don't understand why this happen.

Comment: So if I understand clearly, you are creating a new Blob, then a new ObjectURL, and a new canvas every 30th of a second ? Where are the jpeg coming from? What are you doing of so much canvases ?

Comment: I'm capturing desktop window using c++ server and compress and send to web browser using websocket. when i test this, one size of jpeg is 1280*720 and draw 30 times per second.

Comment: That's still a lot of data for the browser to handle, but I'm more concerned about all the canvases you do *create* every frame. Having only one, and calling only once the `getContext('2d')` method should reduce your memory consumption.

Comment: also makes high memory comsumption. when I use drawImage fast in canvas, firefox has high memory comsumption but chrome is working well...

Comment: You should still keep your canvas and its context in a global variable, avoid the maximum calls in your onload handler. I don't know too much about websocket but can't you send the data directly as Blob instead of converting it in browser ?

Comment: I send image with other info. So I attach morr info into data. So I send arraybuffer and slice. And when I erase one line about drawImage function, memory consumption is less than 10 times.

Comment: Ok, For the drawImage, this is no surprises, because until you call it, the image is not decoded. Also, I'll tell a third time, make the `getContext('2d')` a global variable, e.g called `context` instead of calling it every 30th of a second. I am more interested in the drop you may win in here. Also, you could use only a single image, avoiding to create a lot of load event listeners.

Comment: Is it right? i'm testing this. and same result...

Comment: when I test 1920*1080 30fps movie, In Windows 7,8 memory usage is about 800mb, and somtimes memory usage is continuously increase. but in CentOS 7, memory usage is about 200~250mb.  I don't know it's correct. I was measured using system monitor. and also android, crash.

Comment: and centos7 about:memory has same other measurements with windows. but in system monitor, centos7 memory is more less than windows.